# Any way to detect mistyped urls in python?

Tags: python, error-handling, web

My python program involves going to a user-supplied url and then doing stuff on the page. Ideally, mistyped urls would be recognized and pop up an error. But if they have the right syntax and just don't point anywhere, then either an ISP error page or an ad site is loaded instead.

For example:

"http://washingtonn.edu" --> http://search5.comcast.com/?cat=dnsr&con=dsqcy&url=washingtonn.edu

"http://www.amazdon.com/" --> http://www.amazdon.com/

Is there any way to detect these without knowing all the possible pages? The second one might be pretty hard because it's an actual site, but I'd be happy with catching the first.

Thanks!

Comment: How would you handle mistyped URLs, like `goolge.com`? You'd have to ping tons of permutations of the URL and then decide which of those existing ones is legitimate. It's not something remotely simple IMO.

Comment: What if I mistyped "cnn.com" as "nytimes.com"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless I am misunderstanding your question, what you ask for is impossible, doesn't make sense, or is far far from trivial.

If you think about it, other than a 404 error, where you detect that a page does not exist, if a page does exist there is not way of knowing whether the page is "good" or "bad" as this is subjective. It might be possible to apply some general rules, but you can't make embrace all the possibilities.

The only way would be something like what Google does with the suggestions, but this would imply a huge database with a list of popularity of websites, and test every time for proximity, but that is far beyond trivial and probably not necessary.

For handling 404 statutes in python you could use lie [httplib](http://docs.python.org/library/httplib.html).

Good luck!

Comment: That's kind of what I expected, but since I'm new to this I wasn't sure if there was a redirect or something that would distinguish them.

Comment: @Jeff: Not really, some redirect, other not. There is no general rule applicable to all of the sites. Glad it helped. Just to consider, a viable option would be get the lets say, top 500 sites, and when the user is close enough to one of those, suggest it, but depending on how good this implementation is, it might be harder to code than the application itself, and probably not worth it given the limited list. It just doesn't make much sense. Good luck!!

Answer (score 1):

You can check the [HTTP status code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) of your requests. Probably most interesting for you is the 404 - Not Found status. In the second case, you are right - if the response is a web page, you can't know if is what user wanted or is a typo

Comment: I think he'll also need to disable that pesky Comcast "service", right?

Comment: That is set in his browser I think. Unless he checks the URLs by commanding his browser, that should not appear.

Comment: I could disable it for me, but that doesn't help others using the program.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not entirely sure it's a browser thing. I've always been under the assumption that when it can't find a web address, Comcast issues a 5xx error code, and forwards the user to their Domain Helper service (which would then return a 200 code)...

http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-livingood-dns-redirect-00#page-16

Answer (score 1):

What you're talking about is heuristics and it's actually a very complex topic. You could have a list of common websites and common misspellings- if something cannot resolve (i.e, 404 HTTP response) check the input against the list, and pick the "closest" answer (this is a whole algorithm in-of-itself). It wouldn't be too reliable though, because a misspelled website may indeed resolve correctly (although to the unintended domain).

a really simple solution, if you're very concerned about misspelled urls is to just ask for the URL twice.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regex to check for a valid url, and also use httplib to check for the response codes and require a 200 to continue.

HTTPConnection.getresponse() will return 200 if a url is valid